# Upload a file with php curl from a client to server?

Tags: php, file, curl, upload

I'm trying to upload a file automatically from a client-side script which opens a PHP page in my server sending a local path as a `GET` param. This is a simple python script. My problem is, I can not just fill in the value of an input type file and auto-post the form because for security reasons this doesn't work.

So, I thought of using Curl, but then I realized... I have no way of accessing a `$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']` in my server because this is only posted with a `multipart/form-data form`, right?

Is there a way round this? Is there any other way to upload a file from a browser? It would be ideal to be able to do it with PHP since I'd like to use openID authentication to then save the uploaders email in MySQL database. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't really understood why curl is not a viable solution. Your personal computer files are *not* exposed to the outside by default. Rather than that, if you want to share your hard disc you need to install and configure a lot of things:

1. You need to configure your router so incoming connections are redirected to your PC
2. You need to configure your firewall so incoming connections are let through
3. You need to install a piece of software that can accept and serve file requests (a web server, a FTP server, a NFS server...)
4. You need to instruct such software about what precise files you want to share (you don't want your complete hard disc drive open to the world)
5. You probably want to restrict who has access to your files: username + password, certificate, IP address filter...

If you want to upload a file without user's intervention, the user needs to install a program in his computer that provides the feature: either one of those I've mentioned or a custom program. You can't do it with a barebones standard web browser.

You said something about a *client-side* Python script. Not sure about the meaning of client-side in Python context but Python is definitively able to open HTTP connections and send files. Follow that track.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro for your helpful reply, I understand what you mean. So  what I would be looking for, is a way of replicating the way multipart/form-data sends data to the server. Which I guess is not easy or possible at all ¿? So maybe your idea of using python is the best option, which I'm not looking forward to ... since setting up the openID auth in python is not gonna be much fun :)

Comment: I know nothing about Python but I'm sure it has libraries for both OpenID and HTTP file uploads. It cannot be that difficult.

Comment: I found a solution uploading to a temp folder first using a python FTP library and then moving the file to a specific folder via PHP once he has logged in with his openID, files are automatically deleted from the temp folder after a period of time. Thank you for your help :)