# php curl upload not working on my server

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

My php curl upload script runs successfully on localhost but not on sever..
The curl is working fine for simple post but not for posting files. As soon as i start adding file to my post data ( prefixing file path with @ ), its showing nothing on server ($_FILE & $_POST both is found unset) while without the file, the $_POST is populated . 
I am using following script on my localhost and server too.

```
$request_url = 'http://localhost/curl_upload/curl_upload_process.php';
$post_params['uploadfile'] = '@'.'D:\images\photo-b4.jpg';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I have changed the request_url to the curl_upload_process.php file on the server.
Its working fine on localhost for both simple post and file upload but not on server for only the file upload. Please let me know whats causing the problem to my script on the server.

Comment: Try using verbose of curl.It may help you monitor this.

Comment: Confirm whether curl enabled in your server?

Comment: @likai yes the curl is enabled on my server. and as i said its working for simple post but not file upload. if is send $post_params['name'] = 'Anup'; it reaches to the server successfully.

Comment: @user801662 I have tried your code, It is working. :(

Comment: @likai is it really working on your remote server? if yes, there might be something missing on my server. plz confirm if its uploading/sending file from the client computer to a/your remote server ?

Comment: Yes remote server, but is LAN

Answer (score 1):

hi after much digging i found that you can use the scp command which uses the SSH (Secure SHell) protocol and php have library to use that with in the php code but you need to have the server allowing scp connention

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename', 0644);
?>
```

More detail can be found at [scp+php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php) Hope this can help you :) . Please make change to suit your need

Comment: Thanks for the anwser Dinkar, i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is that when the code in server is executing is filing the file at `@'.'D:\images\photo-b4.jpg';` and not from your machine

where as in case of localhost your machine and server are same so its finding the file physically located at the `@'.'D:\images\photo-b4.jpg';`

in case you what to upload the file you need to make the whole web form request at run time and post that to the server

try some thing like this :- its not the exact code you need to change a bit accordingly

```
    $requestparameters["title"] = $filetitle;

    $content = file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadingfile']['tmp_name']);
    $filefieldname = (array_keys($_FILES));
    $delimiter = '-------------' . uniqid();
    $filefields = array(
    'file1' => array(
    'name' => $_FILES['uploadingfile']['name'],
    'type' => $_FILES['uploadingfile']['type'],
    'content' => $content),
    );
    $data = '';
    foreach ($requestparameters as $name => $value) {
        $data .= "--" . $delimiter . "\r\n";
        $data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $name . '";' . "\r\n\r\n";
        // note: double endline
        $data .= $value . "\r\n";
    }
    foreach ($filefields as $name => $file) {
        $data .= "--" . $delimiter . "\r\n";
        // "filename" attribute is not essential; server-side scripts may use it
        $data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $filefieldname['0'] . '";' .
        ' filename="' . $file['name'] . '"' . "\r\n";
        // this is, again, informative only; good practice to include though
        $data .= 'Content-Type: ' . $file['type'] . "\r\n";
        // this endline must be here to indicate end of headers
        $data .= "\r\n";
        // the file itself (note: there's no encoding of any kind)
        $data .= $file['content'];
   }
   $data .= "\r\n"."--" . $delimiter . "--\r\n";
   $str = $data;
   // set up cURL
   $ch=curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
       CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_POST => true,
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( // we need to send these two headers
            'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$delimiter,
            'Content-Length: '.strlen($str)
       ),
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
   ));
   $ress =   curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I can simply say that your answer must work (for another cases) but i just do not want to browse the file. I have only the paths of files on my machine and i want to upload these files by their paths only. No Browse.

Comment: this post can clearify the use of curl i guess direct file upload is not possible for that you need to use the shell cmd of curl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858644/upload-a-file-with-php-curl-from-a-client-to-server

Comment: i agree. then  how to achieve the same ie uploading files by just knowing their path on the clients machine .